# Error in Spring Security with status code 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

I'm facing some problems with the spring security /login endpoint
I would like to have a auth api but

when I do any post request to the

```
localhost:8080/login
```

this is the response

```json
{
    "timestamp":"2020-11-12T17:00:32.691+00:00",
    "status":404,
    "error":"Not Found",
    "message":"",
    "path":"/login"
}
```

This is my configuration class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(applicationUserService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Comment: are running on tomcat standalone or embedded?

Comment: it is embedded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why!!

I was using this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the right one for my purpose its

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add formlogin() to your configuration:

```
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin();
```

You will not need .antMatchers("/login").permitAll().

Your error looks like there is no login-endpoint at all. formLogin() takes care of its generation.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem before, and I solved it by adding a "/" at the end of the URL.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
```

Comment: then the problem must be from the controller

Comment: if it was from the spring security, it would return a HTTP 401 or 403

Comment: But I think that the login endpoint is autoconfigurated by spring security, i dont have any controller

Answer (score -1):

Please check your controller that you are entering the correct path. There is no issue with the Security Configuration.

Comment: but spring security uses this endpoint as default for login, i dont have any controller in this project